# Purposeful random memory allocations

Tags: c++, memory, random, memory-management, allocation

For an experiment, I want to measure time it takes to find a given record with random memory access. The `record` is a simple class:

```cpp
template<class TKey, class TData>
class Record {
  TKey key;
  TData data;
public:
  Record(TKey key, TData data) {
    this->key = key;
    this->data = data;
  }
};
```

Now I simply allocate memory and insert some records. (Please ignore some syntax mistakes...)

```cpp
const int size = 1_000_000;
Record<int, int> ** data = new Record<int, int>*[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  // allocates sizeof(Record<int, int>) on heap
  data[i] = new Record<int, int>(i, i);
}
```

The issue is, when allocating these new `Record` objects, the are actually stored sequentially in memory. I want these memory locations **to be random**.
Does C++ have any ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Write your own allocator that has a memory pool and picks random, not yet used locations form there?

Comment: _" I want these memory locations to be **random**."_  What does "random" mean, exactly?  If they are not sequential, does that count as _random_?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do here, simply creating `Record<int, int>[size]` and assigning the pointers to the elements of this array to the `Record<int, int>*[size]` array and shuffling the latter before initialization may via the pointers may do the trick...

Comment: _"Please ignore some syntax mistakes"_ - if you _know_ you have such mistakes, why not correct them? If you don't know if you have such mistakes, compile the code (in pedantic / non-permissive mode) to make reasonably sure that you don't have such mistakes.

Comment: Btw, if `TKey` and/or `TData` are expensive to initialize/assign to, you could save a few CPU cycles by using the member initializer list instead of first initializing them and then assigning to them.

Comment: I wanted you to ignore these possible syntax mistakes, as the code is for illustration only and not to be perfect. The answers done by fabian and UnholySheep are actually the one, that might help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answers are commented under the question by UnholySheep and
Fabian. See their comments for the correct answer.